Sharing url from my nextjs app via messenger is showing An error occurred. Please try again later. for some specific recipient

I am using FacebookMessenger Share feature for sharing url from my app. The share is working for some specific recipient and showing An error occurred. Please try again later. for some specific recipient.What could be the reason and how to fix the issue? Is there any alternative to share url via messenger from my app?
